# cant get under category data of json callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

i have a short code of getting json data from another domain, im a newbie in json codes thus i cant understand how do i get the under category data only, for example in this code:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/NewRequest/?Route=2406MOWLON&AD=1&CN=0&CS=E&Partner=testapic&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
    var code=data.Id;
    $.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/Fares/?R="+code+"&V=Matrix&VB=true&L=ru&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push('<li>'+key+': '+val+'</li>');
        });
        $('<ul/>', {
            'class': 'my-new-list',
            html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('#data2');
    });
});
```

im getting the list of currency, lang, sortby and etc, and there is an Airlines category and a lot of objects inside, all i want is to get just these airlines objects and their names(at least they are must be in json data list), how do i do it?!

thank you all for the help, i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to get Airlines name in an unorder list

```
$.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/NewRequest/?Route=2406MOWLON&AD=1&CN=0&CS=E&Partner=testapic&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
    var code=data.Id;
    $.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/Fares/?R="+code+"&V=Matrix&VB=true&L=ru&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if(val && (typeof val == 'object' || typeof val == 'array')){
                if(key == "Airlines"){
                    var airlineNames = [];

                    for(var x in val)
                        airlineNames.push(val[x].Name);

                    items.push('<li>'+key+': <ul><li>'+airlineNames.join('</li><li>')+'</li></ul></li>');
                }
            }else{
                items.push('<li>'+key+': '+val+'</li>');
            }
        });
        $('<ul/>', {
            'class': 'my-new-list',
            html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('#data2');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the airlines, you could loop through 'Airlines' if you know that's the name.

```
var items = [];
$.each(data['Airlines'], function(i, airline) {
    items.push('<li>'+airline.Name+': '+airline.Code+'</li>');
});
```